# Reusing TOC vs bookmarks

Tags: hyperref, memoir, bookmarks

Below is a `memoir` based MWE where we add a few hooks to the TOC and use these to reuse the TOC to mimic a minitoc. This works just fine even with `hyperref`.

However this does not work with the bookmarks. It only corresponds to the data from the last instance of `\tableofcontents`, not the combined information.

Anyone able to explain why it does not just combine the information?

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[
bookmarks=true,
bookmarksnumbered,
colorlinks,
]{hyperref} 

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

% disable TOC part after BREAK
\cftinsertcode{BREAK}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{-10}}

\tableofcontents*

\mainmatter

\chapter{Mainmatter chapter}

\section{Mainmatter section}

\subsection{Mainmatter subsection}


\appendix

\appendixpage

\cftinserthook{toc}{BREAK}

% disable before BREAK
\setcounter{tocdepth}{-10}
% enable after break
\cftinsertcode{BREAK}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}}

\renewcommand\contentsname{Appendices overview}
\tableofcontents*

\clearpage

\chapter{Appendix chapter}

\section{Appendix section}

\subsection{Appendix subsection}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When the toc file is executed by the first `\tableofcontents` the BREAK is configured to do `\setcounter{tocdepth}{-10}`. But hyperref obeys the **then current** value of tocdepth to decide what goes to the bookmarks. So the main matter sectioning does not make it to the bookmarks.

The second table of contents contains a BREAK which sets the tocdepth to 3. So the appendices sectioning coming next end up in the bookmarks.

See also `11.1. The hyperref option bookmarksdepth` in etoc manual.

> When modifying the counter tocdepth for the purposes of multiple uses
>   of \tableofcontents or \localtableofcontents, one should be aware that
>   package hyperref by default takes into account the current value of
>   the tocdepth counter to decide whether the pdf file will contain a
>   bookmark corresponding to sectioning commands encountered in the
>   source file. Thus, one typically needs to reset tocdepth to its
>   previous value after having temporarily modified it for a given table
>   of contents.
>
> Or, there is the bookmarksdepth=n option of package hyperref, with n
>   the desired document bookmarks maximal depth, which can be numeric or
>   the name of a level known to hyperref. This documentation previously
>   passed bookmarksdepth=3 as option to hyperref, so even if tocdepth was
>   left to 1 by inadvertance after printing a certain table of contents
>   this did not modify the bookmark tree of the pdf file. Now that
>   \etocsetnexttocdepth has been added to the package, we have used it
>   systematically and there was no need for bookmarksdepth=3 anymore.

Answer (score 7):

You can set bookmarksdepth individually, then it will work:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[
bookmarks=true,
bookmarksnumbered,
colorlinks,
bookmarksdepth=10 %<-------
]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

% disable TOC part after BREAK
\cftinsertcode{BREAK}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{-10}}

\tableofcontents*

\mainmatter

\chapter{Mainmatter chapter}

\section{Mainmatter section}

\subsection{Mainmatter subsection}


\appendix

\appendixpage

\cftinserthook{toc}{BREAK}

% disable before BREAK
\setcounter{tocdepth}{-10}
% enable after break
\cftinsertcode{BREAK}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}}

\renewcommand\contentsname{Appendices overview}
\tableofcontents*

\clearpage

\chapter{Appendix chapter}

\section{Appendix section}

\subsection{Appendix subsection}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks I'm accepting jfbus answer because of the explanation